# Binding Custom User Control to a RegionContext's Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism-5

I am learning the Prism (ver. 5) Framework, by writing a small HR Application.

My EmployeeSummaryView is a simple master details page which uses a tab control to better organize the properties of type Person. This tab control has a region Context Binding to CurrentEmployee.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }
    public Person EmergencyContact { get; set; }
}
```

Where I am struggling is on the Contact Information tab. Here I use a custom user control for editing the Mailing Address. My first instinct to establish the binding by is to do the following:

```
<local:EditAddressView DataContext="{Binding CurrentEmployee.MailingAddress}"/>
```

But the more I learn about Prism and MVVM, the more this begins to smell.

What is the proper to bind a Custom Control to a property on a RegionContext?

Comment: What about Prism and MVVM makes this a smell?  UCs should be thought of as UI closely aligned with a Type, whether that UI is showing state of the object of that Type, or is editing it, etc.  This is perfectly fine.  What's the smell you are whiffing on?

Comment: @Will Say down the road I want to add additional logic to control whether or not a field can be edited, or maybe a command to do some lookup, there is no viewmodel to place this in.

Comment: Put it in the Address class.  Go on.  Do it.  Blur that line between model and view model.  Because, you know what, it *makes no difference*.  Live life on the edge. It's great out here.  And it doesn't stink.

Answer (score 0):

You're backing yourself into a corner by binding to a Model and not a ViewModel. Wrap your Models with ViewModels and bind to those instead.

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
       ...
       MailingAddress = new AddressViewModel(person.address);
    }

    public AddressViewModel MailingAddress { get; private set; }
}
```